# How do I find out why a java class in oracle is INVALID

Tags: java, oracle, stored-procedures

I have a java class. I load it into Oracle 11 like this:

```
create or replace and compile java source named CubeTester as
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.io.StringWriter;
... etc
```

Oracle responds with "Statement Processed"  -- so it looks like I did things right.. But when I do the SQL statement to find it's validity like this:

```
SELECT object_name, dbms_java.longname(object_name), status
FROM user_objects
WHERE object_type='JAVA CLASS'
AND dbms_java.longname(object_name) LIKE '%CubeTest%' 
ORDER BY 1
```

I get this:

```
 OBJECT_NAME    DBMS_JAVA.LONGNAME(OBJECT_NAME) STATUS
 CubeTester CubeTester  INVALID
```

Now I went and checked every import that I have, and every one of them came back as VALID.  (Except for the java.io.*,  but as that is part of the JDK I assume that that is ok -- Am I wrong?)

And yes,  the code works fine from eclipse (And command line too)

How does one debug this?  The problem is that I am doing this from APEX (SQL Workshop), so I do not have access to the box, I can't use sqlplus or anything like that.  It has to be a single SQL command or something.

Any suggestions on how to proceed?

Comment: Oracle 11gR2 has Java 1.5 to my knowledge.  What version of Java are you compiling in?

Comment: Is there anything in `user_errors`?

Comment: @Nick I am compiling in Oracle as the command says. "Create or repalce and compile"

Comment: @AlexPoole I am getting "ORA-29535: source requires recompilation" so I go and run "alter java source DW.CubeTester compile;"  That runs without error,  but the object is still invalid.

Comment: I think Nick's query was whether you're using the same Java verion in Eclipse as you are in Oracle. If not you may well be using some feature that only exists in a later version and therefore your code won't compile in the older version Oracle is using.

Comment: And there is nothing in the `user_errors` view - `select * from user_errors where name = 'CubeTester'`? (I don't know if there should be,  but that's where I'd look)

Answer (score -1):

try to use this sql command :
`alter java class "Welcome" resolve;`

may be this will solve your problem ,or gives you reason for errors